# Centering a Glyph in a TSpeedButton

Tags: delphi, button, imagebutton, delphi-5

I am building an app (D5) that uses a TSpeedButton and the Glyphs are loaded at runtime.

All good, but the positioning options, Top, Left, Right and Bottom are pretty clunky as a 32 x 32 Glyph on a 40 x 40 button always goes to the top left, right or bottom.

How can I center the Glyph vertically and Horizontally so that the

```
Glyph.Top = 4;
Glyph.Left = 4;
```

and the 32 x 32 picture is centered in the button.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a 40px bitmap and paint your image into it at 4,4. Use that as your glyph.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the reply, but I should have mentioned that the Glyphs are icons from installed programs on the PC. I have no control over them other than selecting the 32x32 version if there are multiple sizes in the program.

Comment: You are a programmer. Of course you can control this. It's trivially easy to do what I describe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Huh? Have I offended you in some way? If it was trivial to **ME**, I would not be wasting **both** our time, asking here. Is there a mandatory level of expertise required to ask questions here? Silly me, I thought this was a Help system. :)

Comment: @user2566616: instead of loading an icon directly into the button, have your code create a `TBitmap`, size it to 40x40, `Draw()` the icon onto it at a 4x4 offset, and then load that bitmap onto the button.

Comment: You've not offended me at all. You just said that what I suggested was not possible. I merely disagreed with that. What I suggested is possible and in fact is extremely easy to do. And it will be easy for you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Layout to blGlyphLeft and Margin to -1. That should center the glyph inside the button.

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried that and it didn't work. It only centered it Horizontally and left it at the top or bottom based on the Layout setting.

Comment: That's why I said "blGlyphLeft".